# Separate by month, with each month having data from beginning of time to end of month in question - SQL

Tags: sql

I currently have a window function that takes all my data and finds the latest value (amount) for each account and then averages this across all accounts.

Now I want to segment by month. The problem is if there has been no data for the account in the month specified we need to get the last possible value used. Therefore we need each month to segment from the beginning of the month to the chosen month. Currently the query provides one value 'average amount'. Ideally I would like this average value for each month from inception

```
SELECT AVG(amount) as "average amount" 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM(
        SELECT account_no,amount,_date,row_number() over(partition by account_no order by _date desc) as rn, source 
        FROM ('another subquery too long to write out fully') k
    ) j
    WHERE j.rn = 1
  ) l
```

Comment: will you post a small sample of the code with the case described above for coding purposes

Comment: Group by the date formatted as YYYY-MM

Comment: What exactly is the problem -- isn't the code you posted the code that gets the last value -- what more do you need?

Comment: I now need to get the average amount for each account no. per month - but if there are no transactions for an account then their balance won't show on the month in question

Comment: build a temp table and insert the segments of data then aggregate the table

Comment: Hi all managed to sort with help of a friend, had to use a recursive CTE